# For which subsystems T of 2nd order arithmetic is there a model of T + $\neg$Con(T)?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, higher-order-logic

A theory T might have the following property: there is a model of T + $\neg$Con(T)

1st order PA has this property, but full 2nd order PA doesn't.

Among subsystems of 2nd order arithmetic, which ones have this property and which ones don't?

With respect to consistency strength, what is the strongest subsystem that has the property, and what is the weakest subsystem that doesn't have the property?

Since some subsystems are incomparable I'm not sure there is a unique strongest with (or weakest without) the property.

Answer (score 1):

Any subsystem of 2nd order arithmetic $T$ in the usual sense (i.e. theory of the sort discussed in Simpson's book or a cousin) is a recursively axiomatized two-sorted first-order theory which includes PA.

Hence Gödel's second incompleteness theorem applies, and $T \not\vdash Con(T)$.

Therefore  $T + \neg Con(T)$  is consistent, and hence has a model by Gödel's completeness theorem.

Comment: It should be remarked that the switch from second to first-order logic is what allows us to use the completeness theorem.

Comment: From another viewpoint, we are not switching to first-order logic: in reverse mathematics and similar areas we use second-order logic with Henkin semantics. Of course, this is a fine distinction, but it can sometimes be good to keep in mind.

Comment: It's also important to remember that if $T$ is the set of axioms for $Z_2$, we still have $T \not \vdash \text{Con}(T)$. There is no completeness theorem for full semantics, and in fact $T \vDash \text{Con}(T)$ in full semantics, but the incompleteness theorem still shows that $T$ cannot *prove* its consistency under any effective deduction system. (My first comment was more a response to Asaf's; this one refers to the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

As the question points out, second-order PA with full semantics is categorical, and its only model is the standard model. But the set of axioms for that theory is extremely small: finite, with 9 axioms in one common axiomatization. In particular, there is only one induction axiom:
$$
(\forall X)[0 \in X \land (\forall n)[n \in X \to Sn \in X] \to (\forall n)[n \in X]]$$
and there are no comprehension (set-existence) axioms at all (these are often taken as logical axioms in full semantics, like the axioms for equality).

So it makes little sense to look at subsystems of that theory - which of the 9 axioms would you omit?

When we talk about subsystems, we move to Henkin semantics. The difference is that we no longer insist that the second-order part of each model must be the powerset of the first-order part. Now we have to include set-existence axioms (as a scheme) in our theory, because otherwise the second-order part of a model might be empty. This extended set of axioms, whose syntactic consequences give a theory known as $Z_2$, is the theory we use for forming subsystems of second-order arithmetic. Each of these subsystems, $S$, has a model of $S + \lnot \text{Con}(S)$, as long as it meets the hypotheses of the second incompleteness theorem (effectiveness and sufficient strength).

Comment: I am surprised by what you say about subsystems: I thought "subsystem" of a theory $T$ just meant a subset of the deductive closure of $T$ (or if you like your theories to be deductively closed by definition a deductively closed subset of $T$). You seem to be implying that a subsystem has to be given by a subset of the axioms in some given axiomatization of $T$. Is that usual terminology?

Comment: Your thought is right - for example $\mathsf{WKL}_0$ is a subsystem in your sense of $Z_2$ but the defining axiom of $\mathsf{WKL}_0$ is not one of the axioms of $\mathsf{Z}_2$. However, to form a proper subsystem, one must first remove *some* axiom(s) and then possibly add new ones. What I was saying is that when we form subsystems, we don't do it from the deductive closure of the 9 Peano axioms. Those axioms (which don't even mention addition or multiplication, much less comprehension) will have some proper subset of $Z_2$ as their deductive closure, and not a very interesting subset.